# How to fix broken hinge on Macbook Air 1st generation

Tags: laptop-repair, macbook-air

I am proceeding to fix on my own the first generation Macbook Air with a broken hinge. All the cables and connections are okay but the hinge is physically splitting open, with one side no longer connecting to the top display to the bottom. I have seen videos of how to open it, and it isn't hard, but my issue is how to find replacement for the hinge.

Worst scenario, I will be 3D printing the hinge. I have a makerbot, and don't mind DIY.

Please help! If I find out more, I will add updates here too.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious solution would be to call Apple directly and ask for that part. But I am pretty sure that they wont help you at all.

Have you tried looking on the web for broken macbook airs? If they are severely damaged (water, from falling) you will get them cheap, but probably can scrap an undamaged hinge out of it.

Comment: yup, it is actually a defect on Apple website support, but they don't cover it for many more reasons, you know? There are a lot of excuses at their diposal. I opened it up, and found the hinge is truly damaged without repair and is damaging other cables too. Sounds like finding spare parts is the way to go. I like the scavenge idea.